# DXA Framework issue (without the Core)

Tags: dxa

I am working on Web 8.5 and DXA 1.7, without the Core module.  I created a new Publication as a child of 110 Site Type and I also created a new Page View and associated Template in the CMS.  My page is now Published so, in theory, I am expecting to see my Page View content before I start creating things like Entity Views, Models etc.  I get the following error:

> Sdl.Web.Common.DxaException: Localization [35 ('English')] does not
>   contain includes for Page Type '1881'. Check that the Publish Settings
>   page is published and the application cache is up to date.    at
>   Sdl.Web.Common.Configuration.Localization.GetIncludePageUrls(String
>   pageTypeIdentifier)    at
>   Sdl.Web.Tridion.Mapping.DefaultContentProvider.GetIncludesFromModel(IPage
>   page, Localization localization)    at
>   Sdl.Web.Tridion.Mapping.DefaultContentProvider.GetPageModel(String
>   urlPath, Localization localization, Boolean addIncludes)    at
>   Sdl.Web.Mvc.Controllers.PageController.Page(String pageUrl)

Comment: Did you publish the "Publish Settings" page?

Comment: I did Rob.  However, along with an answer from Bart, I checked the BinaryData folder and noticed everything isn't making it through.  If I copy an existing BinaryData (DXA) folder from a working environment then it works so I think I need to find out why Publish Settings isn't working for me.  Thank you...

Comment: Sounds like a familiar issue https://tridion.stackexchange.com/questions/12759/localization-100-english-does-not-contain-includes-for-page-type-99999

Comment: As discussed it sounds more like a fluke in your publishing, or caching on the Content Delivery side, let us know when yo figure it out, so we can answer this question.

Comment: If none of your binaries make it through to the BinaryData folder: is your CIS configured to store binaries in the DB?

Comment: Preview your Publish settings page. and you should see all the content on CMS servers's preview folder. or check in Content DB

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you

- try to republish your `_Sytem/Publish Settings` page
- and either restart the webapp, or call `http://host:port/admin/refresh` to make sure that the new configuration, mappings, and other stuff including information about include pages is available in the web application.

Since you are setting up DXA website without Core module, I guess you are setting it up from scratch. Did you keep/create the settings page? DXA really needs to have the settings published, otherwise weird things happen.

The error message comes from `Sdl.Web.Common.Configuration.GetIncludePageUrls(string pageTypeIdentifier)` [see source](https://github.com/sdl/dxa-web-application-dotnet/blob/release/1.7/Sdl.Web.Common/Configuration/Localization.cs). This error can occur either when

- the settings are not published and the `includes.json` cannot be loaded;
- or when the settings are out of date and the Page Template of your Page is not in the includes mapping.

Comment: Since he created his Publication as a child of `110 Site Type`, the settings page is automatically inherited through Blue Printing, as are the `Publish HTML Design` and include pages.

Answer (score -1):

Without the core, my guess would be that you have no default page controller. Take a look at the page controller in the core on github, then implement your own.

Comment: The standard Controllers are part of the DXA Framework (`Sdl.Web.Mvc`), so you don't need the Core Module to use those.